# Erro na funçao count do php.Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in line 41

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendario</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Dom</th>
            <th>Seg</th>
            <th>Ter</th>
            <th>Qua</th>
            <th>Qui</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Sab</th>
        </tr>
        <?php calendario(); ?>

    </table>
    <?php
        function linha($semana)
        {
            echo"
                <tr>
                    <td>{$semana[0]}</td>
                    <td>{$semana[1]}</td>
                    <td>{$semana[2]}</td>
                    <td>{$semana[3]}</td>
                    <td>{$semana[4]}</td>
                    <td>{$semana[5]}</td>
                    <td>{$semana[6]}</td>
                </tr>
            ";
        }
        function calendario()
        {
            $dia =1;
            $semana = array();
            while($dia<=31){
                array_push($semana, $dia);
                if(count($semana == 7)){
                    linha($semana);
                    $semana = array();
                }
                $dia++;
            }
        }

        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto está errado:

```
count($semana == 7)
```

Quando faz `$semana == 7` você pega um booleano (true ou false) e não o array propriamente, provavelmente deveria ser:

```
count($semana) == 7
```

Comment: Brigado cara ta funcionando agr!

Comment: @BillyJean se resolveu, não deixe de marcar a resposta com ✔️. Recomendo ler a página [tour] do site.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas comentando uma alternativa, você pode utilizar as funções `range` e `array_chunk` para gerar as semanas que deseja:

```
$semanas = array_chunk(range(1, 31), 7);
```

Isso gerará o array:

```php
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 11
            [4] => 12
            [5] => 13
            [6] => 14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 19
            [5] => 20
            [6] => 21
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 23
            [2] => 24
            [3] => 25
            [4] => 26
            [5] => 27
            [6] => 28
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 31
        )

)
```

Então poderia fazer algo como:

```php
foreach ($semanas as $semana) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($semana as $dia) {
    echo "<td>{$dia}</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Saída:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Obviamente que este código não considerará casos que o mês não se inicia no domingo.